# Chainlink Job IDs for single word response in Polygon mainnet?

Tags: polygon, chainlink

I have followed the tutorial to query a custom API URL in Göerli test net here:

https://docs.chain.link/docs/any-api/get-request/examples/single-word-response/

And it works like a charm.

Also I have seen this page in chainlink that shows the list of Job IDs and Oracles to GET > UINT256 in different testnetworks:

https://docs.chain.link/docs/any-api/testnet-oracles/

All looks great, but I cannot find what is the right Job ID oracle to achieve the same in Mainnet.

After googling for a while I found this great tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ay4rXZhAefs&t=19s

But when they come to explain the Job IDs and oracles, they suggest to go to market.link and find nodes for get > uint256 and in the video seems to be a lot of options.

But when I go to the same site (looks like they changed the look), I got:

https://market.link/nodes/Get%20%3E%20Uint256/nodes

Only one node for Kovan.

So, I am lost, my question is:

How can I run this example in Polygon Mainnet?
https://docs.chain.link/docs/any-api/get-request/examples/single-word-response/

Are there any oracles / job Ids available?

Thanks

Comment: You could go to the discord and ask a node operator to host your data. Market.link looks like it's no longer supporting any API calls. https://discord.gg/FSVmJ9p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

| Job = (Get > Uint256) | Oracle Address=`0x3d5552a177Fe380CDDe28a034EA93C2d30b80b2D`| External Job ID=`a052732022e04e89be3e0fc06e457985`| Fee=0.10 LINK |

Our discord server containing all our chainlink oracle addresses and jobId's: https://discord.gg/QAnR267Y

Answer (score 1):

In the end I went to the Chainlink discord: https://discord.gg/u8FwQxSQ and there is a channel called operator-requests, there you can find node operators for your needs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for mainnet , read this page for an explanation how to find an oracle https://docs.chain.link/docs/any-api/find-oracle/

> **Community node operators**
>
> To find an Oracle Job that is pre-configured for your use case and available  on the right network, join the [Chainlink operator-requests discord channel](https://discord.gg/eGcxsdZzKR) to directly communicate with community node operators.

Answer (score 0):

Chainlink community node operator here.

As [market.link](https://market.link/) has been deprecated, the next-best way to find a oracle and job id is to join the Chainlink Official Discord server, and post your request to the **#operator-requests** channel.

You may also feel free to browse our comprehensive list of oracle addresses and job ids on all blockchains, which are documented [here](https://docs.linkwellnodes.io/services/direct-request-jobs/mainnets).

(ie, Polygon `GET` -> `uint256` job can be found [here](https://docs.linkwellnodes.io/services/direct-request-jobs/mainnets/Polygon-Mainnet-Jobs?dataType=Uint256))

I hope that helps!